# Validation Formula throws an Invalid Syntax Error - Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, formula, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am trying to create a validation formula in order to perform the below logic.

- `I_Priority__c` is a Picklist
- `C_Start_Date__c` is a Date Field
- `C_End_Date__c` is a Date Field

These field values cannot be duplicated in the database. Therefore every new entry to be inserted needs to be validated accordingly.

For this,
I am using the below formula

```
NOT(EXISTS((SELECT Id  FROM I_Coverage__c  
 WHERE I_Priority__c = {{I_Priority__c}}
   AND C_Start_Date__c = {{C_Start_Date__c}}
   AND C_End_Date__c = {{C_End_Date__c}})))
```

When I press the 'Check Syntax' button, I am getting

> Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is... very misguided. You can't run queries in formulas like that and where's that `{{syntax}}` coming from. Are you a Marketing Cloud person or something?

I'll list some options but you have lots of reading to do.

- **If it was Account/Contact/Lead/Person account** - you could use duplicate rules. You have a custom object so go upvote an idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZjcUAF/potential-duplicates-for-custom-objects, read the comments, maybe there's an app you can use.
- You could look into **VLOOKUP function** - but it'd require the 3 values all appear in the Name field of the object which may be a no-go for you.
- you could **write an apex trigger or flow** but properly protecting the scenario may be harder than you think.

  - How do you not detect "yourself" (I'm updating an unrelated field on a record, how do you ensure it won't find itself)
  - How do you protect an insert of 2 identical records at same time (say with Import Wizard or Data Loader) - your query could return 0 pre-existing records in the database and let it through
  - What if I insert #1, delete it, insert #2 (exact duplicate), go to recycle bin and restore #1? Validation rules don't fire on `undelete`

---

So... is there an easy config solution? Yep.

1. Create a helper text field, `Unique__c` Text, 255. Mark it Unique case insensitive.
2. Create an "early flow" or `before insert, before update` trigger if you feel like it, populating the field with combination of your 3 fields. No conditions, can run always (low performance impact and `before` means it's a save for free).
3. Run a data fix that mass updates your records (if you did #2 you can just "touch" them, update without changing anything, should populate.
4. Try to break it.